# No DNS for root?

Tags: configuration, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It seems my configuration for root doesn't have access to DNS even though my lower-privileged user does.

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.251.32.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 142.251.32.110 (142.251.32.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.35 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.110 (142.251.32.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.71 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.350/2.029/2.708/0.679 ms

$ sudo -E ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

This is wreaking havoc with `apt-get`.  How can I troubleshoot this?

I am running WSL Ubuntu.

## Edit 1

It looks like `root` is trying to use `localhost` for DNS.

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
```

The equivalent line for unprivileged me is this.  I think that `172.*` address is some WSL thing.

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.21.160.1")}, 16) = 0
```

This is what `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like.

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.21.160.1
```

## Edit 2

Root is not able to read `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", 0x7ffc8a2d25f0, 0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I updated the `automount` settings in my `wsl.conf`.

```
[automount]
root=/home/myuser
```

Once I reverted this change `root` was once again able to access the internet.  I believe this is due to a boot order problem because `/home` is not available soon enough to configure the network for `root`.